# Run Apple's StoreKit on a server

Tags: ios, storekit

I know people sometimes run cut down versions of iOS in weird environments. How might I run the StoreKit framework from a server, is this feasible?

Specifically, I want to make SKProductRequest calls from my server (to determine price info about purchases). You would typically do this on the client.

Comment: `SKProductRequest` only goes to Apple's servers. If you are using IAP then you can't use your own servers.

Comment: I want to send the SKProductRequest to Apple, but I want to receive the response on a server, not an iOS device. So, I want to somehow initiate the SKProductRequest from the server, and I need to know the StoreKt internals or run StoreKit to do that.